# What is the best way to perform a Create/Update into an SQL table

Tags: t-sql

I've got a situation where I want to either create a row if it doesn't exist, or update it if it does exist.  Is there a good clean way to do this is TSQL?

Comment: If you're going to downvote me, add useful feedback please.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but this question (or variants of it) has been [asked many times](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql+server+update+insert+row+exists) on SO, so you may have been downvoted for lack of research

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE ...)
    UPDATE table SET ...
ELSE
    INSERT INTO table ...